# How to repeat an entire process in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Consider the following code

> x = y+3;
>
> y = input('??');

What can I do to ask the user to continue or not, if yes then it prompt the input function for y again, if no then terminate the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while true
  % Do stuff
  inp = input('Continue? (y/n) ', 's');
  if ~strcmp(inp, 'y')
    break;
  end
end
```

**Edit:** Based on our discussion, I'm adding an example of how you could structure a Matlab file with two functions, a `main` function running the above loop, and a `helper` function that is called inside the loop.

```
function main()
  while true
    inp = input('Enter y: ', 's');
    y = str2double(inp);
    helper(y)
    inp = input('Continue? (y/n) ', 's');
    if ~strcmp(inp, 'y')
      break;
    end
  end
end

function helper(y)
  x = y + 3;
  fprintf('x = %.2f\n', x);
end
```

More info on Matlab functions [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Comment: if I type y then the process end, what if I wish to repeat it. Because when I type y using the command above it just keep continue asking me "Continue?"

Comment: Typing 'y' makes it continue. Typing 'n' (or anything else for that matter) will break the loop.

Comment: ya..but typing 'y' it doesn't return back to my very first command and repeating the entire process...hmm.....

Comment: You obviously have to replace `% Do stuff` with your actual computation that you want to perform in a loop.

Comment: How about creating a function with the operation that needs to be done in the loop, and just call that function there?

Comment: erm how to call the function if I have created it...hmmm...thanks a lot for helping me this far

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21550/discussion-between-green-and-3lectrologos)